# Querying MongoDB in C# web app is much slower than C# console application, why?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Im currently working on a project where we have to increase performance and therefore have moved from retrieving data from a relational database and calculating figures, to pre calculating figures and store them in a mongodb document.

But now when we are doing speed tests we can see that the application is not faster. The query time when retrieving the data from the relational database and calculating the numbers takes about 0.8s. Whereas retrieving the pre calculated data from the mongodb takes 2.5s in average.

So we tried to do a test with a console application, where we can see that the same query to the mongodb only takes 40ms in average.

What can cause this huge difference in the querying time?

We use the same MongoDB driver v.2.3 in both the web app and the console app. They both connect to the same collection and searches for the same item.

For measuring time we use the c# System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch

This is the function used to query

```
public BsonDocument findByProp(ObjectId id)
    {
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
        var collection = getCollection("collection").Find(filter);

        return collection.First();
    }
```

This is how its called and measured

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        var club = m.findByProp(new MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId("5823327fc3a41f31d849cf3b"));
        sw.Stop();

        var elapsedTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

The web app and console test are run on localhost connecting to the same cloud server. The elapsed times are averages calculated over 100 consecutive tests. So this should also take in account of any caching

Comment: using the same database collection? How do you measure the time? Edit your question and add this info.

Comment: I\ve updated the question, they both test against the same collection and searching for the same item. I use the c# stopwatch to measure the time

Comment: Do the console application and the web application both reside in the same network / cloud / data center where the database resides (e.g. have you eliminated network latency as a potential cause)?

Comment: Maybe first query is cached then second gets from there? MongoDB keeps all of the most recently used data in RAM. If you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory. Was data bigger than ram of server?

Comment: The web app and console test are run on localhost connecting to the same cloud server. The elapsed times are averages calculated over 100 consecutive tests. So this should also take in account of any caching.